# A concentration problem

Tags: probability

Consider $N$ variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N$ with $\Pr(X_i=a_i)=\Pr(X_i=-a_i)=1/2$. Here $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_N\in [0,1]$.

Does there exist some concentration result about $\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$?

Comment: Do we have any information on how the $a_i$ are distributed in $[0, 1]$?

Comment: $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_N$ are fixed. e.g. $a_1=0.1, a_2=0.2, a_3=0.5$

Comment: For a symmetrical distribution, I would have guessed that the probability scaled the same way

Comment: I think @BrianTung is asking what the distribution is during their selection?  How are the $a_i$ distributed?  Normal, uniform, other?

Comment: @MichaelTimback: But we don't know, otherwise, how they're scattered in $[0, 1]$?  For instance, they might all be close to $0$?  Or they might equally likely be all close to $1$?

Comment: @BrianTung All $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_N$ are deterministic and $N$ is a finite number. For arbitrary deterministic $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_N\in[0,1]$, does there exist a lower bound?

Comment: You still haven't answered my question, I'm afraid, and I think it makes a difference.  For instance, if all the values are close to $1$, then the probability of being in that range is on the order of $3/\sqrt{\pi n}$.  If the values are all close to $0$, the long-term behavior is also $O(n^{-1/2})$, but the constant will be much larger.

Comment: @BrianTung OK. I think it can be assumed that the distribution of $a_i$ is unknown. Is there a common lower bound of $\Pr(-1\le X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_N\le 1)$ for any distribution of $a_i$?

Comment: Without knowing anything more about how the $a_i$ are distributed, the best lower bound that can be obtained assumes that all the $a_i$ are equal to $1$.  However, this will not in general be a tight lower bound.  If, for instance, $\sum a_i \leq 1$, then the probability is equal to $1$.

Comment: @BrianTung I understand your words. For example, $1/\sqrt{2N}$ is a lower bound for the case when all $a_i$'s are $1$. I have tried a lot but I still cannot prove that $1/\sqrt{2N}$ is a common bound of $\Pr(-1\le X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_N\le 1)$ for any distribution of $a_i$. Could you help me or provide some references about it?

Comment: @MichaelTimback Just  prove that $\Pr(-1\le X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_N\le 1) \leq \Pr(-1\le a_1 X_1+\cdots+a_N X_N\le 1)$ if all $a_i \leq 1.$

Comment: @iiivooo It seems not to be obviously correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S(a,\epsilon)=\sum_{k=1}^N \epsilon_i a_i$ with $\epsilon=(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_N)$ and  $\epsilon_i\in\{\pm 1\}$ independent and uniformly distributed, and $a_i\in [0,1].$ We can actually assume $a_i\leq a_{i+1}$ (since the signs range over all of $\{\pm 1\}^n,$) and take $a_i\in (0,1]$ since otherwise we can reduce the dimension $N$ and reconsider the problem for $N'<N.$

Clearly $S(a,\epsilon)=-S(a,-\epsilon)$ so the distribution of $S(a,\epsilon)$ is symmetric around zero. Let any lower bound $B$ on $$\mathbb{P}\left\{|S((1,\ldots,1),\epsilon)|\leq 1\right\}\geq B$$ for the case $a=(1,1,\ldots,1)$ for all $1\leq i\leq N$ be given. Recall that we can assume $0<a_1\leq a_2\leq \cdots \leq a_n \leq 1.$

Define the all one vector as $a^{(0)}$ and now consider the vector 
$$a^{(1)}=(a_{i^{\ast}},\ldots a_{i^{\ast}},1,\ldots,1)$$
where we define $a^{(1)}_i=a_{i^{\ast}}$ for all $i\leq i^{\ast}.$

**Lemma:** Let $Z$ be any symmetric random variable, with support on the integers. Then $Z+\epsilon a$ where $\epsilon=\pm 1$ with equal probability
satisfies the inequality
$$\mathbb{P}\left\{|Z+\epsilon a|\leq 1\right\}\geq \mathbb{P}\left\{|Z+\epsilon |\leq 1\right\}$$ whenever $a\in (0,1].$ This can be seen by the fact that the probability mass function of $Z+\epsilon a$ is the sum $$\frac{q(z-a)+q(z+a)}{2}$$ while that of $Z+\epsilon$ is the sum $$\frac{q(z-1)+q(z+1)}{2}.$$ Here $q(z)$ is the probability mass function of $Z.$
This is because $a_{i^{\ast}}<1$ and the random sums $S(a^{(1)},\epsilon)$ are ``more central'' than the sums $S(a^{(0)},\epsilon)$ since their distribution result from at least one convolution with dominated random variables on $\{-a_{i^{\ast}}, a_{i^{\ast}}\}$ 
instead of random variables on $\{-1,1\}.$

The Lemma's argument can then be repeated using induction and applying it to compare
$$S(a^{(0)},\epsilon)\textrm{ with } S(a^{(1)},\epsilon),$$
and then moving from $a^{(1)}$ to $$a^{(2)}=(a_{i^{\ast}-1},\ldots a_{i^{\ast}-1}, a_{i^{\ast}},1,\ldots,1)$$
and applying the argument to obtain that
$$\mathbb{P}\left\{|S(a^{(2)},\epsilon)|\leq 1\right\}\geq B$$
still holds. Then use $a^{(3)},$ etc to finish the argument.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't understand how to derive that $|S(a^{(1)},\epsilon)|<|S(a^{(0)},\epsilon)|$. For example, let $a^{(1)}=(0.5,1,1)$ and $\epsilon=(-1,1,1)$. Then $S(a^{(0)},\epsilon)=1>0$ but $S(a^{(1)},\epsilon)=1.5>1=S(a^{(0)},\epsilon)$.

Comment: See updated answer, I didn't need that property.

Comment: I think the "more central" argument is somehow not rigorous. Still use the example $a^{(1)}=(0.5,1,1)$. We can obtain that $\Pr(|S(a^{(1)},\epsilon)|\le 1)=1/2$ but  $\Pr(|S(a^{(0)},\epsilon)|\le 1)=3/4$.

Comment: I realize that this example can serve as a counterexample to imply that $\Pr(-1\le X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_N\le 1) \leq \Pr(-1\le a_1 X_1+\cdots+a_N X_N\le 1)$ is not always correct. But I guess we can still get a lower bound of order $O(1/\sqrt{N})$.

Comment: thanks, I still think I can fix my argument, but I will need more time :-)

Answer (score -1):

If $a_i$ are deterministic, than you can think about new random variables  $Y_i=\frac{X_i}{a_i}$ and you already have the lower bound for this.